# Is the measure word optional in 这件毛衣?

Tags: grammar

I've heard the sentence `这毛衣`, (so without measure word), but my chinese manual always use a measure word after `这`:

> 这件毛衣
>
> 这件苹果

Is the measure word optionnal in after `这` ?

Comment: `件` is a Unit/classifier/量詞. Sometimes it is optional, sometimes not. I have a small section about that in my other answer [here](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/2615/2263).

Comment: 这件苹果?? Unless you are somehow referring to a brand name?

Comment: @JamesJiao - Even if it is a brand name you can not use `件` there.

Comment: @BAK - `件` is just like in English, where you say `a glass of water`, `a loaf of bread`. You can not just say `I want a water` or `I ate a bread`, right? Same in Chinese. Sometimes you need `件/個/條`, but sometimes you don't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Mandarin, especially Northern China dialects, measure words can be omitted when

1. It is following a demonstrative pronoun (e.g. 这, 那), AND
2. The numeral is 1 (one), AND
3. It is not a collective measure word （e.g. 些, 群).

The grammatical role of the phrase does not change. E.g.

> 这一件毛衣 = 这件毛衣 = 这毛衣
>
> 这一些毛衣 = 这些毛衣 collective measure word 些 cannot be omitted.

Comment: I have heard of 这个苹果 and 这粒苹果, but never encounter 这只苹果 when referring to an apple. Is it also part of Northern dialects?

Comment: @QuestionOverflow no it's not. Actually I heard this usage from people from the south. Searching 一只苹果 online there are some hits suggesting the usage does exist though may not be correct.

Comment: @QuestionOverflow As a native speaker from South China, I'd like to say I've never heard of "这粒苹果", 粒 refers to something very small(a pill, a grain of rice, etc) in general.

Comment: @NS.X. Actually, you can use 这件苹果 in real life where 件 means "a box or package", so 这件苹果 means “this box of apples". Can you update your answer?

Comment: @QuestionOverflow 粒 gives a feeling of an accent from HongKong. Where did you hear it?

Comment: @Huang I've removed the comment about measure word for an apple from the answer. In Beijing 这件苹果 sounds absolutely weird and people wouldn't think it's a box of apple...

Comment: I would think 这粒苹果 would be a little chunk of apple. Like if an apple exploded all over the place, you would go around picking up the 苹果, one 粒 by 粒.

Comment: @Huang, I hear it quite often in Singapore. A Google search on "这粒苹果" produces 212,000 results. There are people using it in Malaysia and Taiwan too though I am not too sure about its appropriateness. I am quite surprise that "这只苹果" produces even more result because I thought 只 is a 量詞 for animals or human parts. Both 粒 and 颗 refers to small objects, and 颗 is for more rounded objects. As for how small is considered small, this is quite subjective. Maybe there isn't a suitable 量詞 for 苹果 causing people to use different versions. I think the safest is still to stick with 个 :)

Comment: Does it also have a formal touch without the measure word?

Comment: @EnricoBrasil No it's actually less formal without measure word.

Answer (score 0):

“这毛衣” works, but it means "this sweater"; while "这件毛衣” means "this /*measurement word in English for 件*/ of sweater"; they are different grammatically.
Just like: these shoes Vs. this pair of shoes